# Parameterized SQL UPDATE Statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have seen many examples of the parameterized SQL queries, but have run into a few questions.

I know I am not hashing passwords, so please disregard that.

The following is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET username=@uName, pwd=@pWord, role=@uRole, actuser=@uActive WHERE ID=" & recordID
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uName", tbUsername.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pWord", tbPassword1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uRole", cbRole.SelectedItem)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uActive", isActive)
```

The error I get is:

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

I don't understand why because everything in the database is "Short String" except for "actuser" which is set to Yes/No and "isActive" is set to "Yes" when the code attempts to run.  I have validated the table column headers to be accurate and I don't know why this is not working.

This format seems to work with an INSERT statement, but not an UPDATE statement... but I can't confirm that right at this moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Updated code with same error.

```
 Dim isActive As Boolean = False
    If cbxActive.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        isActive = "True"
    End If

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET username=@uName, pwd=@pWord, role=@uRole, actuser=@uActive WHERE ID=@ID"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uName", tbUsername.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pWord", tbPassword1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uRole", cbRole.SelectedItem.ToString())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uActive", If(isActive, "Yes", "No"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", recordID)

    myConnection.Open()
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try`
```

SelectedItem is returning a string from a collection in a combobox.

Here is my DB structure.[Link to Picture of Access DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EKtl.png)

Here is the other structure pic. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBDq8.png)

Comment: Dont use `AddWithValue` - it makes the Provider guess at the data type.  `cbRole.SelectedItem` for instance is Object.  There is usually more to the exception indicating which type which would give you a clue.  Of course we have no idea what type `isActive` is -  sounds like it should be boolean, but we cant see it's declaration.  The recordID could/should also be a parameter.

Comment: `except for "actuser" which is set to Yes/No and "isActive" is set to "Yes"` theres the problem (if accurately described).  First, MySql doesnt have a yes/No column type, normally you'd use tinyint.  But Yes/No is an Access-ism, but it is just another name for Boolean.  If you are passing `"Yes"`, that is a string which is a mismatch

Comment: Just guessing, since your code doesn't show the declaration for variable or database table: is `recordId ` the correct data type?

Comment: a few doc pages on it, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/12379/executing-sql-statements-as-a-command#t=201611162242582223866)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have noted that "isActive" is declared as String.

'Dim isActive As String
        If cbxActive.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            isActive = "Yes"
        Else
            isActive = "No"
        End If'

This is an access database, not mySQL.  Improper tag.

Comment: Ok, oledbexcept message is exactly this:  Additional information: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, we can only guess what is in `isActive` and `cbRole.SelectedItem` but we know for sure that one of these if not both, causing your issue.

Specifically, you can use `AddWithValue` only when direct match type is used. otherwise you need to precisely set parameter data type like this

```
Dim p As New OleDbParameter(@pName, OleDbType.SomeType)
p.Value = [your value]
cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
```

In your case these 2 lines could be [scratch that] are! problematic

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uRole", cbRole.SelectedItem)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uActive", isActive)
```

first line returns object that can be anything (only you know). What to do with it

```vb
' If selected item is string
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uRole", cbRole.SelectedItem.ToString())
' If selected item is integer
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uRole", CInt(cbRole.SelectedItem))
' If selected item is complex object in which you use property
Dim val As Integer = DirectCast(cbRole.SelectedItem, MyObjectType).SomeIntProperty
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uRole", val)

' If your value 'isActive' is boolean and you keep Yes/No in DB, you need this
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uActive", if(isActive, "Yes", "No"))
' and opposite
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uActive", if(isActive = "Yes", 1, 0))
' you have to be careful here. In .NET false=0, all else <> 0. so, if your business logic needs True=1, all else <> 1, you need to convert correspondingly
```

And last thing - why not parameterize `...WHERE ID=" & recordID...`? do exactly same thing

```
cmd.CommandText = ". . . . . WHERE ID= @id"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", recordID)
```

Comment: @MattBrown so, you need to use `if(isActive = "Yes", 1, 0)`. Also, when I said "structure", I mean: user varchar; id integer.... etc

Comment: Thank you so much, that was correct and fixed the problem!  I'm sorry about not posting an accurate first post, I will do that in the future.  I'm new to paramaterizing and your suggestions and tips really helped me learn!  Thank you again!

Comment: @MattBrown Enjoy! don't forget to up-vote as well. thank you